# blue marker current location in leaflet api

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

hi i use the web map and i need to show current location like map.google.com or openstreetmap.or blue svg how can show ?

```
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').fitWorld();
    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=token', {
        maxZoom: 18,            
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("you " + radius + " data").openPopup();
        map.setZoom( 18 );
        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16}); 

</script>
```

Comment: When you just add a normal L.marker in current view, do you see the default Leaflet Marker icon?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the blue marker by default, you can create your own Icon:

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/